# Can't assign DOM element value to a variable

Tags: javascript, dom, undefined

Using JavaScript I obtain an undefined variable error using different code:

**HTML form**

```
<form name="someForm" onsubmit = "return submitAnswers()" >
<input type="radio" name"w1" value = 'a' id="wla">a.
```

**Javascript**

```
function submitAnswers(){
    var w1 = document.forms["someForm"]["w1"].value;
 }
```

The same result is obtained trying to assing an initial value;

```
function submitAnswers(){  
var w1 = 'some'
w1 = document.forms["someForm"]["w1"].value;
}
```

I then receive the following output:

> TypeError: document.forms.someForm.w1 is undefined

Comment: because `"w1" !== w1`, you have the string, not a variable because of the quotes.

Comment: Console.log `document.forms["someForm"]` and see what it return and check if `w1` exist on the object

Answer (score 0):

You forgot the "elements" property.
https://developer.mozilla.org/fr/docs/Web/API/Document/forms

you should have something like : `w1 = document.forms["someForm"].elements["w1"].value;`

edit: this code works absolutely fine for me :

```
<form name="someForm" onsubmit="return submitAnswers()"  method="POST" >
    <input type="radio" name="w1" value = 'a' id="wla">a.
    <input type ="submit">Submit</input>
</form>
<script>
    function submitAnswers(){  
          var w1 = document.forms["someForm"].elements["w1"].value;
          console.log(w1)
          return false;
    }  
</script>
```

I get a console log :  "a"

Comment: I stiil have an error: var w1 = document.forms["someForm"].elements["w1"].value; someForm.elements.w1 is undefined

Answer (score 0):

Fix `name"w1"` to `name="w1"`. And use [`elements`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLFormElement/elements) property of Form as @Who Knows showed.

Comment: Now it works. Thanks! I didn't realize the missing '='